# Portable Development Environment

Tags: grails, virtual-machine

I am working on a huge Grails Project, and more and more people are going to be working on it.
The problem is that I have been spending ages setting up people's machines (java etc etc).

I heard that there is something like a VM that you can set up on your machine once and transfer on other people's computers.

Also what about performance issues? Lets say I install a VM on other people machine that will slow down things no?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will be very bad in performance as VM runs as a full fledged machine with OS on top of it. If you have all systems with very high configuration like quad-core i7's and minimum of 8Gb rams then only systems will be able to handle such load.

Still it will be a bad idea to do so. And while running grails you already have multiple instances of java running like in my case with netbeans I have 2 resource hungry java instances running with 700mb and 500mb respectively.